# How to sort list based on it's corresponding ascii values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, ascii

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']
```

How to sort this list values based on it's corresponding `ascii` values ?

```
sorted(list1, key=len,reverse=True)
Outputs      : ['abcd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
ascii values : [394, 294, 297, 195, 197, 199, 97, 98, 99, 100]
```

Tried this, which prints ascii values. But may be I required to store in dictionary. And then sort it and then extract. Any simple and optimal way of handling it (may be with mapping or not using any other lists/dicts).

```
for i in list1:
    print(i, sum(map(ord, i)))
```

Expected output based on ascii (descending order):

```
['abcd', 'bcd','abc','cd','bc','ab', 'd', 'c', 'b','a']
[ 394  ,  297,  294,  199, 197, 195, 100,  99,  98, 97]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Based on its ASCII value ['abcd', 'bcd','abc','cd','bc','ab','d','c','b','a'] it's in descending order.

Comment: @superbrain  list to be in descending order based on ascii values.  Output posted above is obtained based on key=len (not ascii)

Comment: @superbrain May be that confused you. Updated with expected output, hope that's clear now. Down-voted because  of that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use your ascii conversion function as the sort key to sort by those values:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']

print(sorted(list1, key = lambda s: sum(map(ord, s)), reverse=True))
```

Output

```
['abcd', 'bcd', 'abc', 'cd', 'bc', 'ab', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Note that this will leave values in `list1` which have the same ascii value sorted as they were in the original list (since python sort is stable). You may want to sort them in the same order as the rest of the list (so for example `'da'` would sort before `'ad'`), in which case you can just add the current value to the key function so that it sorts first by the ascii value and then the actual string:

```
sorted(list1, key = lambda s: (sum(map(ord, s)), s), reverse=True)
```

Thanks to @superbrain for the input to these edits.

Comment: Thanks for adding up the efficient info.

Comment: @StackGuru no worries - I'm glad it was useful. There's another advantage to sorting the zipped list, which is that when the `ascii` total is the same, it will sort by the actual string, so (for example), `'da'` will sort before `'ad'`.

Comment: Typically, sorting by several criteria (like that "advantage" of the second solution) is done with the key function as well, like `lambda s: (sum(map(ord, s)), s)`. So similar to the zip solution, but doesn't require that extra pass to then get the values back out of the pairs.

Comment: @superbrain (keep wanting to read that as super brain :) I'm not familiar enough with python internals to know whether that does actually require a second pass, it seems like it should be reasonably easy to optimise away. But what you say makes sense regardless and I will remove that part of the answer.

Comment: That's of course the whole point of this name, and I figured people would just type @-s-tab and be too lazy to add the space :-). I guess with second pass you mean something internal and talking about efficiency? That's not what I meant, I just meant your list comprehension, i.e., more code on your part.

Comment: @superbrain yes, that's exactly what I meant, it's more typing but probably just as fast. Regardless, it's redundant, as you pointed out, and I've removed that part of the answer and replaced it with what you've said in the comments, with the appropriate attribution

Comment: Yes, speed should be about the same. Here's a test: https://repl.it/repls/PointedPlainTabs#main.py (not a good *sorting* test due to the poor data, but I think it suffices to compare the overheads of the different methods, at least functions `g` and `h`).

Comment: This is why I love this site... the people who want to improve all the answers. I ran your demo and got 3x slower results (weird since I presume it's running on their server) but also in one case `h` was about 15% faster than `g`. Not sure what's going on there; your results make much more sense.

Comment: Yeah, timing stability is the main reason I included my PC's time. I love repl.it for what it provides, but being a server used by others as well, it's not the most stable speed-wise. On my PC, I can make reasonably sure that it's not harmed by other processes and that the CPU speed doesn't change (much).

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'abc', 'bcd', 'abcd']

print(sorted(list1, reverse=True, key=lambda k: sum(ord(ch) for ch in k)))
```

Prints:

```
['abcd', 'bcd', 'abc', 'cd', 'bc', 'ab', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution where you use the list of corresponding `ascii` values.

```py
sorted_list1 = [i for _, i in sorted(zip([sum(map(ord, x)) for x in list1], list1), reverse=True)]
sorted_list1
output : ['abcd', 'bcd', 'abc', 'cd', 'bc', 'ab', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the key by a function
Since you mean the sum of all chars in the string as the ascii value, you could define a method to produce ascii value and sort by it

```
def to_ascii(var):
    if len(var) > 0:
        # sum by char
    else:
        # return ascii

sorted(list1, key=to_ascii, reverse=True)
```

Output:

```
['abcd', 'bcd', 'abc', 'cd', 'bc', 'ab', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```